# Specify maximum CPU and memory utilization of ABAP Application Server

Tags: abap

Is there any means to configure an ABAP application server to that it does only consume X percent of CPU usage and Y percent of memory on the machine it runs on?

Or is this rather something that is only possible on the operating system level?

Google research revealed [how to view the operating system status](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_ewm94/helpdata/de/ab/77d1325a874cd887c0321e6b07b9bf/content.htm?no_cache=true). As this is only viewing, I would be interested in a means to control this status also from within the ABAP application server.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of a method to bind the memory allocation of an application server to a manually adjusted percentage of the host OS memory. There are several profile parameters that control the different memory types used in an application server. SAP offers a [detailed documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_nw70/7.0.31/en-US/02/9626c0538111d1891b0000e8322f96/frameset.htm) on their memory management.

As far as I know, the maximum memory allocated by an application server is controlled by the size of the roll area for work processes, the extended memory and the total heap size. Profile parameters for those settings are:

- [ztta/roll_area](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_nw73/7.3.16/en-US/49/3433b45cce5717e10000000a42189b/content.htm?no_cache=true) / [ztta/roll_first](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw73/helpdata/en/49/76d3c8b5de423ae10000000a421938/frameset.htm) (per work process, not total)
- [em/initial_size_MB](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70/helpdata/en/02/9626e7538111d1891b0000e8322f96/content.htm?no_cache=true)
- [abap/heap_area_total](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_nw70/7.0.31/en-US/02/9626da538111d1891b0000e8322f96/content.htm?no_cache=true)

Work processes first receive memory from the roll area, after that they can request more memory from the extended memory up to the size of [ztta/roll_extension](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_nw70/7.0.31/en-US/02/9626b3538111d1891b0000e8322f96/content.htm?no_cache=true). If all extended memory is allocated, the work process can allocate heap memory (with a few downsides, which is why that is happening only when necessary)

The biggest influence on memory will be `em/initial_size_MB` and `abap/heap_area_total` (with `em/initial_size_MB` being the main control mechanism). I'd focus on those two to adjust the total memory consumption of your application server instance.

Side note: `em/initial_size_MB` has a default of 70 % of the total host memory, so there is already a percentage based memory allocation happening in the kernel as long as that parameter isn't set. But I'm not aware of a way to influence the percentage used by the kernel.

**Update**, thanks to mkysoft for the information: the two parameters `CPU_CORES` and `PHYS_MEMSIZE` are by default set by the operating system and contain the total number of CPUs and the total memory installed in the system. You can manually override them, reducing the resources the SAP kernel uses to calculate default values for several kernel parameters. You could for instance reduce `PHYS_MEMSIZE` and leave `em/initial_size_MB` to default. Both parameters also allow you to set a percentage instead of absolute values. You could for instance set both values to `50%`, reducing the maximum resources for that application server instance to 50 % of what the hardware has to offer. There's some [additional documentation](https://help.sap.com/viewer/b17bd20044a44edb9aa7830ee52ffac3/7.4.19/en-US/51319798cc7a428a896af0bc2a00adc7.html) for those two parameters available as well.

Comment: May be CPU_CORES parameter can be used for limiting CPU utilization. You can check RZ11 t-code for all configs.

Comment: @mkysoft I looked up CPU_CORES and PHYS_MEMSIZE, it seems you can set both of them manually, overriding the values provided by the operating system. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for shedding light here.